# Load Apple Maps App with Placemark - slow performance

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

When ill load any placemark from my app into the Apple Maps App - it takes up to 15 Seconds to show a route.

First you see for maybe 1 second your position, then you see North America, and then (after 10-15 Seconds) you get your route.

Is there any chance to optimize the performance here? This is how i start the route at the moment (Ill provide already a lon and lat value)

```
let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(lat),longitude: CLLocationDegrees(lon)), addressDictionary: nil)
let aMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark
aMapItem.name = mapItem.name
let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking]
let currentLocationMapItem:MKMapItem = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()

MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([currentLocationMapItem, aMapItem], launchOptions: launchOptions)
```

Thanks in advance.